# Window.print print from second page

Tags: javascript, css

I want to print a web page but printing begins with second page.The first page is white...
The printing is with the window.print method.
My print.css:

```
body{
    width:100% !important;
}
a[href]:after 
{ 
    display:none; 
    text-decoration: none;
}
iframe
{
    display:none;
}
object{
    display:none;
}
.pinkbar,.greybar,.site_slogan,.search_container,.four 
{
    display: none;
}
.article_container{
    width:100% !important;
}
.contentbar{
    min-height: 10px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
table td{
    vertical-align: top !important;
}
#content-print td{
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: top !important;
}
```

I want to print the content from the first page...Help me please....

Comment: I don't get how we can help you with css... show us your javascript

Comment: The script is simple : onclick="window.print();return false;"

Comment: where ? on which element ? show html